# How to achive card scroll animation using framer-motion?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I am trying to achieve the animation on cards when they are scrolled as shown in the following link .
In the below example, I want the animation done in the right-hand side cards ( fade off when they are out the view ).

[LINK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/ekqoe?file=/ui/index.ts)

I had used the `whileInView` attribute of framer motion, from [Docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/#scroll-triggered-animations). But it not what I expected.

#### Below is my code, but it is very long. However you can take simply 6 cards in 4x2 (4 rows, 2 cols) as an example.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import imgurl1s from "../public/mssmall.png";
import imgurl1l from "../public/mslarge.png";
import Image from "next/image";
import {
  SiBootstrap,
  SiFramer,
  SiJavascript,
  SiLichess,
  SiMongodb,
  SiNextdotjs,
  SiPostman,
  SiReact,
  SiRedux,
  SiTailwindcss,
} from "react-icons/si";
import { FaNodeJs, FaEye, FaHtml5, FaCss3, FaSpotify } from "react-icons/fa";
import { HiCode } from "react-icons/hi";
import { AiOutlineApi } from "react-icons/ai";
import { motionValue } from "framer-motion";


const Projects = () => {

  const currentOffSetY = motionValue(0);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="min-h-full">
       
        <div className=" mx-auto shadow container">
          <div className="px-4 py-6 sm:px-0">
            

            <div className="p-5 border-2 border-red-400/20 flex flex-col lg:flex-col items-center justify-center ">
              <div className="p-2 sm:p-10 flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center space-y-3 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-16 justify-center">
                {/* card1  mschatapp*/}
                <div className="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute ">
                  <div
                    
                    className="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row md:max-w-6xl md:max-h-96 hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100"
                  >
                    <div className="block sm:hidden">
                    <Image
                      height={350}
                      width={700}
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg "
                      src={imgurl1l}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                    <Image
                      width="500%"
                      height="1000%"
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                      src={imgurl1s}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between p-3 leading-normal ">
                      <h5 className="mb-2 text-lg sm:text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 ">
                        ms-chatApp
                      </h5>
                      <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-xsm sm:text-base  text-justify text-gray-700 ">
                        ms-chat-app is the macro version of ms-teams where you
                        can form groups and can message & share images with
                        different people. You can also customize the UI by
                        yourself.
                      </p>
                      <hr className="m-auto text-black bg-black" />
                      <h3 className="text-sm sm:text-base text-black font-semibold">
                        Technologies
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-black flex flex-row space-x-3 py-2">
                        <span>
                          <SiReact className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiMongodb className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150  hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <FaNodeJs className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiPostman className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-4/5 mt-3 lg:mt-5 mx-auto  bg-slate-300  rounded-lg">
                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Live"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <FaEye size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>

                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Code"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <HiCode size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* card2 */}
                <div className="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute ">
                  <div
                    
                    className="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row md:max-w-6xl md:max-h-96 hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100"
                  >
                    <div className="block sm:hidden">
                    <Image
                      height={350}
                      width={700}
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg "
                      src={imgurl1l}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                    <Image
                      width="500%"
                      height="1000%"
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                      src={imgurl1s}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between p-3 leading-normal ">
                      <h5 className="mb-2 text-lg sm:text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 ">
                        ms-chatApp
                      </h5>
                      <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-xsm sm:text-base  text-justify text-gray-700 ">
                        ms-chat-app is the macro version of ms-teams where you
                        can form groups and can message & share images with
                        different people. You can also customize the UI by
                        yourself.
                      </p>
                      <hr className="m-auto text-black bg-black" />
                      <h3 className="text-sm sm:text-base text-black font-semibold">
                        Technologies
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-black flex flex-row space-x-3 py-2">
                        <span>
                          <SiReact className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiMongodb className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150  hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <FaNodeJs className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiPostman className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-4/5 mt-3 lg:mt-5 mx-auto  bg-slate-300  rounded-lg">
                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Live"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <FaEye size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>

                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Code"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <HiCode size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="p-2 sm:p-10 flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center space-y-3 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-16 justify-center">
                {/* card3 */}
                <div className="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute ">
                  <div
                    
                    className="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row md:max-w-6xl md:max-h-96 hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100"
                  >
                    <div className="block sm:hidden">
                    <Image
                      height={350}
                      width={700}
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg "
                      src={imgurl1l}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                    <Image
                      width="500%"
                      height="1000%"
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                      src={imgurl1s}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between p-3 leading-normal ">
                      <h5 className="mb-2 text-lg sm:text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 ">
                        ms-chatApp
                      </h5>
                      <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-xsm sm:text-base  text-justify text-gray-700 ">
                        ms-chat-app is the macro version of ms-teams where you
                        can form groups and can message & share images with
                        different people. You can also customize the UI by
                        yourself.
                      </p>
                      <hr className="m-auto text-black bg-black" />
                      <h3 className="text-sm sm:text-base text-black font-semibold">
                        Technologies
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-black flex flex-row space-x-3 py-2">
                        <span>
                          <SiReact className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiMongodb className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150  hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <FaNodeJs className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiPostman className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-4/5 mt-3 lg:mt-5 mx-auto  bg-slate-300  rounded-lg">
                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Live"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <FaEye size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>

                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Code"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <HiCode size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* card4 /}
                <div className="card w-full h-full bg-transparent hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover: hover:to-[#b2eff7] transition hover:rounded-lg hover:drop-shadow-3xl hover:ease-in-oute ">
                  <div
                    
                    className="transition p-2 flex flex-col items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-[#ffa0ae,5%] to-[#b2eff7]  rounded-lg border shadow-md sm:flex-row md:max-w-6xl md:max-h-96 hover:cursor-pointer hover:from-[#ffa0ae,5%] hover:to-[#b2eff7] hover:transition hover:duration-500 ease-in-out  opacity-90 hover:opacity-100"
                  >
                    <div className="block sm:hidden">
                    <Image
                      height={350}
                      width={700}
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg "
                      src={imgurl1l}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                    <Image
                      width="500%"
                      height="1000%"
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                      src={imgurl1s}
                      alt=""
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between p-3 leading-normal ">
                      <h5 className="mb-2 text-lg sm:text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 ">
                        ms-chatApp
                      </h5>
                      <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-xsm sm:text-base  text-justify text-gray-700 ">
                        ms-chat-app is the macro version of ms-teams where you
                        can form groups and can message & share images with
                        different people. You can also customize the UI by
                        yourself.
                      </p>
                      <hr className="m-auto text-black bg-black" />
                      <h3 className="text-sm sm:text-base text-black font-semibold">
                        Technologies
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-black flex flex-row space-x-3 py-2">
                        <span>
                          <SiReact className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiMongodb className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150  hover:rounded-xl" />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <FaNodeJs className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          <SiPostman className="hover:text-purple-900 hover:border-[1px] hover:border-purple-900 hover:scale-150 hover:rounded-xl " />
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-4/5 mt-3 lg:mt-5 mx-auto  bg-slate-300  rounded-lg">
                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Live"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <FaEye size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>

                        <button
                          className="bg-indigo-900 text-sm sm:text-base text-white p-1 px-2 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-800  hover:cursor-pointer transition duration-50 ease-in-out"
                          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                          data-bs-placement="bottom"
                          title="See Code"
                        >
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            target="_blank"
                          >
                            <HiCode size={18} />
                          </a>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Comment: hey did you achieve it ?